# Difference between "go down to" and "get down to" (some location)

Tags: phrase-usage

Consider these two expressions:

> I have to go down to the ATM.
>   I have to get down to the ATM.

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: In this particular case there's no substantive difference. *Get* is more informal (you wouldn't use it an academic essay), and it has a slight overtone of effort, but the meaning is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

The second expresses a sense of urgency lacking in the first.